# How do I declare "Random" if at all?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So this is for unity an ai scrip using Random to find 2 different results but its giving me the error cs0104 which is

> "an ambuiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and 'System.Random'

and I'm not quite sure how to fix this... it may just be me working on it too long my brain is fried but ... man
this is the code I'm working with

```
private void SearchWP()
    {
        float rndmZ = Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);
        float rndmX = Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);

        wPoint = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + rndmX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + rndmZ);

        if (Physics.Raycast(wPoint, - transform.up, 2f, theGround))
        wPointSet = true;
    }
```

Comment: You can include the namespace which should avoid the compiler confusion. Example, can you change `Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);` to `System.Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);` ?

Comment: @h0r53 no because OP wants to use `UnityEngine.Random` .. otherwise it would be e.g. `var rnd = new System.Random(); var rndmZ = rnd.Next(-wPointRange, wPointRange);` ;)

Comment: Sure, my point was to include the namespace of the `Random` that is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error simply means you have both

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
```

on top of your file which allow you to address the types included in these namespaces directly without everytime having to address them by the full namespace type name.

However, as the error tells you both namespaces contain a type called `Random`, [`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.random) and [`UnityEngine.Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) so the compiler does not know which one you want to refer to.

From your usage it looks like you want to use `UnityEngine.Random`.

So you can do that by addressing it via the full namespace

```
float rndmZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);
float rndmX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-wPointRange, wPointRange);
```

or by putting a

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

on top of your file

Comment: yes thankyou I changed it to UnityEngine.Random.Range and it works :D